# C++ Primer - Pointers and References to an Array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

In C++ Primer 5th Edition, Section 3.5, page 115, it gives the following example:

```
int *ptrs[10]; // ptrs is an array of ten pointers to int
int &refs[10] = /* ? */; // error: no arrays of references
int (*Parray)[10] = &arr; // Parray points to an array of ten ints 
int (&arrRef)[10] = arr; // arrRef refers to an array of ten ints
```

I understood almost all the exemples, except the one:

```
int (*Parray)[10] = &arr; // Parray points to an array of ten ints
```

To point to an array, I could just do something like:

```
int a[10];
int *p = a;
```

Since the name 'a' is also a pointer to the array, now p points to the same place that the pointer indicated by the one represented by the name 'a'.

I tried to compile the example given by the book and I was expecting that using:

```
int (*Parray)[10] = &arr; // Parray points to an array of ten ints
```

would have the same effect as in the example I gave. The problem is that does not happen, here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    int arr[10] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
    int *ptrs[10];
    int (*Parray)[10] = &arr;
    int (&arrRef)[10] = arr; 

    cout << *(Parray + 1) << endl;
    cout << Parray[1] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles, and gives the following output:

```
0x7fff5c4a2ab8
0x7fff5c4a2ab8
```

Could someone explain exactly what:

```
int (*Parray)[10] = &arr; // Parray points to an array of ten ints
```

is ? and what I can do with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could someone explain exactly what:
>
> ```
> int (*Parray)[10] = &arr; // Parray points to an array of ten ints
> ```
>
> is ? and what I can do with it ?

The type of `Parray` is `int (*)[10]`, meaning it can only be assigned to the pointer to an object of type `int [10]`.

So, what you have is a pointer pointing to the start of an array(as obtained by `&arr`) of 10 elements.

And the way to access the elements of `arr` through `Parray` will require you to first dereference the pointer `Parray` to obtain the `arr` which you can index into:

Hence doing

```
(*Parray)[5] = 546;
```

assigns the 5th element to 546, resulting to what the expression below will do.

```
arr[5] = 546;
```

As seen [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b381bed6b53b08cf).

Answer (score 1):

It is just pointer to the array with certain elements.
You wrote that you can simply use pointer `int *p = a;` It is correct, but this pointer can point not only on certain array. Technically pointer p points to the first address of the first element in the array. `int(*Parray2)[10]` pointer only  to the array with 10 elements, because static array signature is T(&)[N].
Using the array signature you can write for example method which can return the size of the static array:

```
template < size_t N, typename T > size_t GetSize( T(&)[N] )
{
    return N;
}
...
int arr[10] = { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 };
auto sz = GetSize(arr);
```

If you want to work with pointer you can use it in different ways, but int(*Parray2)[10] can point only to the array with 10 elements:

```
int arr[10] = { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 };
int arr2[11] = { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 };

int *bare_ptr1 = arr; // legal
int *bare_ptr2 = new int(); // legal
int *bare_ptr3 = arr2; // legal

int(*Parray)[10] = &arr; // legal
int(*Parray2)[10] = new int(); // compile error
int(*Parray3)[10] = arr2; //  compile error

cout << bare_ptr1 << endl;
cout << &arr[0] << endl;
cout << *(Parray + 0) << endl;
cout << Parray[0] << endl;
```

if you want to see address difference you can get address of the PArray, and address of the array. Those addresses must be different.

```
cout << &Parray << endl; // address of the pointer which points to the array
cout << &arr << endl; // addres of the first element in the array
```